# What is the purpose of the resistor \$R_L\$ in active peak detector circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I initially thought \$R_L\$ was the load resistor, but then my textbook suggests to use a voltage follower to drive small load resistor. However it uses the voltage follower ***without removing*** \$R_L\$. Is there any use of \$R_L\$ ?  Why can't I connect the capacitor directly to the voltage follower?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The resistor across the capacitor provides a galvanic path that you probably want to keep. Also, there's probably at least one (probably two) additional resistor(s) I'd add, that circuit (a) doesn't show.

Comment: @jonk is the additional resistor in series before capacitor to limit charging time of capacitor? (I'm going to google galvanic path..)

Comment: A galvanic path is anything where electrons can travel. Wire. Resistors. Etc. Nothing spectacular. How is it that the capacitor might discharge, and how quickly, if the resistor weren't present? Without that resistor, it may "leak" through the input to the (+) input of buffer (b) and may leak via the (-) input in circuit (a) -- both of which may have PN junctions or just mosfet gates -- and it might leak through the reverse-biased diode. But these are tiny (usually.) There's more bad stuff with those schematics, too. Imagine a bipolar opamp at (a) with diff-pair inputs. See any problems?

Comment: Oh so the capacitor must be discharged and be ready for the new \$v_{in}\$. Without \$R_L\$ it would take forever to discharge. I get it! Perhaps a practical circuit may have a reset mechanism which shorts the capacitor everytime before applying fresh \$v_{in}\$? I see these textbook circuits are mostly for educational purposes and some tweaking is needed to make them work better  in practice..

Comment: With bipolar opamp I think it results in *input offset current* which shifts the output voltage from the actual peak...

Comment: That's a factor to consider. But now suppose that the (+) input pin of the circuit (a) opamp is very much lower than the (-) input? What would be the input current at the (+) input? What would be the input current at the (-) input? (In a bipolar case.)

Comment: if (+) input is close to \$0\$, then \$I_{b+} \approx 0\$.

Comment: For (-) input the large voltage across capacitor is connected to the base of bjt. This may force the bjt to saturate and collector diode to forward bias, and in FF bias, large base current may flow till the capacitor gets discharged... Hmm interesting when you look inisde the diff amp stage..

Comment: Pardon if I don't make much sense with above reasoning. I feel a bit clueless :(

Comment: Actually, I think you are getting it. This is pretty much what I also wanted you to look into, more deeply. Most bipolar opamps will operate with very low base currents into their (-) and (+) inputs, so long as the voltage difference is not more than about a volt (in better cases -- or more than a few hundred millivolts in worse cases.) But when the difference gets large, the base currents get quite large. No longer anything like what's on the datasheet. But usually in the milliamps (if the the sources can supply it anyway.) A well-managed design requires some thinking.

Comment: @jonk so the base currents get quite large when the differential input is > 1 volt. I'll review diff amps some more and get back if I don't understand. You're a big help thank you so much:))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is there any use of \$R_L\$ ?*

If the circuit doesn't contain \$R_L\$, there is no path to discharge C. The op-amp can't discharge C because there is a diode in the way - the op-amp has only the ability to charge C up to a larger voltage.

So, \$R_L\$ is there to slowly discharge C i.e. it's a slow reset circuit. If there wasn't an \$R_L\$ component you would see the red waveform below for Vout i.e. it is a true peak detector with no reset: -

[image]

With \$R_L\$ present you get a slow discharge like this and you are able to detect the final peak (at the expense of a slowly deteriorating "hold" value: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://electronicscoach.com/peak-detector.html).

So, it's a peak detector that responds quickly and "saves" the largest voltage it's just been subject to and slowly deteriorates that saved voltage so that the next peak can be detected. An alternative to the resistor is a logic control line and a discharge MOSFET: -

[image]

Just like in one of your previous questions about the integrator, you can use a resistor and get an approximately good performance without the need for reset intervention OR, you have a reset mechanism that isn't automatic.

Answer (score 1):

The load resistor represents whatever circuit or device you want to apply the peak voltage signal onto. The whole point of your circuit is to deliver a signal representing the peak voltage of the input signal to the load. You can't remove the load because then there would be no point to building the circuit to begin with.

That said, I don't think the material you cited is very clear about how you'd connect the follower. The complete circuit, with the follower, should look like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5Pd9n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The buffer amplifier (OA2) is inserted between the sampling capacitor of the peak detector and the load.

> Why can't I connect the capacitor directly to the voltage follower?

The capacitor is connected to the voltage follower. It's connected to the input of the voltage follower.

**Edit**

As mentioned in comments, some path is needed to discharge the sampling capacitor between peak events. I've added an `Rd` to the schematic. By adding the buffer amplifier you're able to choose the value of `Rd` independently from (higher than) the value of `Rl`.

Comment: Your C1 has no discharge path.

Comment: The shown circuit (assuming an IDEAL capacitor) will not work when the actual sample is LOWER than the former one. The capacitor cannot be discharged.